# Etymology of "rabona"

Tags: etymology, word-usage

In association football, [rabona](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabona) is used to describe a specific technique:

> a method of kicking the football whereby the kicking leg is wrapped around the back of the standing leg—effectively with one's legs crossed.

Do we have anything regarding the etymology and origin?

Comment: The etymology of *nutmeg* was dealt with [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43124/etymology-of-nutmeg), so I've edited it out of the question to avoid duplicates.

Comment: And *rabona* is dealt with adequately in the linked Wikipedia article. It's Spanish.

Comment: Wikipedia deals with the Spanish word, and it's first use in Spanish, but not with its use in English.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Callum Alexander wrote in ["Who Invented the Rabona Kick?"](http://callumjamesalexander.wordpress.com/2012/10/30/football-article-who-invented-the-rabona-kick/):

> The first rabona actually dates all the way back to 1948 in a match between Argentinian teams Estudiantes de la Plata and Rosario Central. It was Estudiantes de la Plata player Ricardo Infante that scored the historic goal and **it was an Argentine football magazine that came up with the term ‘rabona’ for it. The expression comes from ‘hacerse le rabona’, which in Argentina means to skip school without your parent’s permission, in reference to Infante ‘skipping’ the use of his weaker foot with the move**.
>
> Infante spoke about the trick in 1998 on the 50th anniversary of the goal. “That goal didn’t get the recognition it deserved. At the time we didn’t have televised and media coverage of every game,”
>
> It is this lack of coverage that meant Giovanni Roccotelli was credited with its invention in 1978 when he used it to set up a goal by his Ascoli team-mate Giacomo Tafuro against Modena.

It's been used in English since at least the mid-1990s. The earliest I found in Usenet is from rec.sport.soccer, by Ariel Mazzarelli on [25 August 1995](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rec.sport.soccer/0JloEsM0NFM):

> > Are you talking about Amato? The guy who dribbled past 3-4 defenders and
> >     then fired that...what do you call it?...that foot-behind-foot shot that
> >     scared the crap out of Higuita?
>
> The lack of response is probably due to some sort of oath of silence.  I will tell you,  but you forgot
>   where you heard it,  ok?  It is a **rabona**.
>
> Ariel

Ariel Mazzarelli, who often used Spanish terms in his English, also used it on [29 September 1995](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rec.sport.soccer/FMhkn0JRU0c), and here on [17 July 1996](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rec.sport.soccer/g2xBYo-Y9dM):

> Like an actor needs a stage, or a politician needs a bribe, our Seleccion
>   needs eleven opponents to score golazos against. Will it be a taquito? Perhaps
>   a big caño? Ah, to truly mystify you, a **rabona** would surely do! For
>   pedagogical purposes, many paredes will be shown. And it would be a rare thing
>   to see, but surely useful, if you saw what a real bicicleta was, so that you
>   would not persist on misnaming the chilena.

Finally, here's a [6 March 1998](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rec.sport.soccer/A-RAU1gwYDs) rec.sports.soccer use in articles from Nando and Reuters, re-posted by Bill Bride about Spanish football:

> Rivaldo is so strongly left-footed that he has perfected an
>   extraordinary manoeuvre, known as the **'rabona'**, to compensate for his
>   lack of right-sided striking power.
>
> The **'rabona'** involves bringing the left foot behind and around the
>   right to hit the ball. Rivaldo is yet to score with the trick, but has
>   given defences some nasty moments.

Comment: And the best example I can remember seeing was the improbable centre by Maradonna (running flat out) when he seemed to have let the ball run too far into the right-hand corner of the field. Thankfully, a colleague (whose name I forget) headed in the superb cross.

Comment: Surely the Argentinian example should be _hacerse **la** rabona_?